# Showlabels not readable for subfigure

Tags: subcaption, showlabels

When `subfigures` are added using the package `subcaption`, the labels generated in the pdf by the `showlabels` packages are  not readable.

The `subcaption` package is included before `showlabels` package. How can I correct this?

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{plots/membrane/error_H1_rel_1d_100_11_11.pdf}
        \caption{Full RBs}
        \label{fig:membrane_recon_error_full_RB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{plots/membrane/error_H1_rel_1d_100_11_7.pdf}
        \caption{Full primal RB and truncated dual RB}
        \label{fig:membrane_recon_error_truncated_RB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Reconstruction error for points in and outside training set}
    \label{fig:membrane_recon_error}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: As always on this site please post some minimal code reproducing the issue.

Comment: Added minimal code @campa

Comment: The problem persists even if you replace subfigure with minipage and remove the subcaption package.  Alas, \marginpar doesn't work on floats and \marginnotes will overlap itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a new environment queuelabels which prevents showlabel from overlapping labels within.  It uses the url and marginnote packages to format and print the labels.

Note: it takes two runs for the labels to show up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\normallabel=\label
\usepackage{showlabels}

\newsavebox{\labelbox}
\newenvironment{queuelabels}{\def\label##1{\normallabel{##1}%
  \global\setbox\labelbox=\vbox{%
    \hsize=\marginparwidth\raggedright
    \ifvoid\labelbox\else \unvbox\labelbox\vskip\baselineskip\fi
    \url{##1}}}}%
 {\dimen0=\ht\labelbox
  \marginnote{\unvbox\labelbox}[-\dimen0]}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{queuelabels}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Full RBs}
        \label{fig:membrane_recon_error_full_RB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Full primal RB and truncated dual RB}
        \label{fig:membrane_recon_error_truncated_RB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Reconstruction error for points in and outside training set}
    \label{fig:membrane_recon_error}
    \end{queuelabels}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I get the following error:
``[10]
Runaway argument?
{\@firstoffive }\fi  for two cases of full and truncated dual RB. As \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.
<to be read again> ``

Comment: \My@setref@link sounds custom.  I can't find it being used in any package I have installed.